# Some objects aren't shown (2D)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am unable to see some of created objects (with prefabs) unless I'm close to them in 3D or when I start the game, but in 2D editor they are shown. Video demonstration: https://streamable.com/8d2sn

What I tried:

- Checking Z level: All platforms are on Z 99, background is on 100.

Comment: That might be a problem with the 'order' of your layers.

Comment: i changed it in hierarchy but it was working like before, nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all of the platforms are on the same Z axis and make sure that they are not too close to the camera. Also, change your game window from free aspect to your screen ratio.

Comment: Z 99 for all platforms camera z 0 background z 100. I tried other aspect ratios nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your transform.position.z axis is set to a large number, I would suggest either adding this script on to your object:

```
void Update () {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.z = 1f;
        transform.position = pos;
}
```

Or see if your object has an animation on it then make sure you delete or set the transform.position.z to 0 or 1.

Hope this helps!